# Storing a file in Swift 2+ from URLSession

Tags: file, swift2, nsdata, nsurlsession

I'm downloading a large file and when it finishes the

```
URLSession(session: NSURLSession, 
           downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
           didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL)
```

method gets called.

I want to save the resulting file locally,  `NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory` for instance.
But I'm having some issues with this, mainly because the files are quite large 500MB+

I have tried:

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(savePath, 
                                                contents: fileData, 
                                                attributes: nil)
```

Which works fine for smaller files < 100MB but larger files die with

```
Code=12 "Cannot allocate memory"
```

When trying to convert the downloaded file to NSData like this:

```
let data: NSData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: location,
                              options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
```

The question is, is there another way to convert the `location: NSURL` to `NSData` just so there are no memory issues with large files?

Or is there a better way to save the large file other than `NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath()` just so it doesn't require `NSData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `NSFileManager`'s [copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:) to copy the file from location to wherever you want